# How to monitor process state changes?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to write a watchdog that keeps track of some processes that are generally badly written.

I've tried 3 things.

- Check `/proc/<pid>/stat` once every 2 seconds to see if the process is chocking on some lock, etc. But this method is resource intensive and more importantly not accurate.
- On some private processes that I have written I send heartbeat like messages but that isn't possible on 3rd party closed source software.
- I did come across `CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS` but is very limited in it's functions.

On Linux, is there a way to receive process state changes that notify a listening process when the process goes to sleep or become uninterruptible? Or is there a better way to audit a process' behaviour?

Comment: If you want to be more intrusive, there's `ptrace`...

Comment: A similar though not identical question has been answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90628/18202). Unfortunately, that answer is in the negative, but you might find it illuminating in any case.

Comment: @thb That's exactly what I did in option 1. Note, this is useless as the process might've changed states during the interval and come back to the same state. We'd now be seeing it as if the state has never changed.

Comment: the functions: `wait()` and `waitpid()` are called in the parent.  Those functions can return for several reasons, like the child is stopped, the child received a signal, the child terminated, etc.  by calling `waitpid()` can narrow it down to a specific child process

Comment: @user3629249 This is unrelated 3rd party daemons that I don't `fork()`/`exec()` myself.

Comment: Process state can change many times (over one thousand) state in one second.  Monitoring state change (as when a process enters kernel mode vs. user mode) requires a process that changes state to acquire that info.  There's a quantum mechanics issue in this subject.